# Máximo de ocorrências num dicionário python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Se eu tiver o dicionário:

```
meu_dic = {A:3, B:5, C:0, D:10, E:2}
```

resultante de:

```
meu_dic = {i:lista.count(i) for i in lista}
```

Eu sei que **A** aparece 3 vezes na lista, **B** 5 vezes, etc..
Como é que eu consigo retornar o valor máximo de repetições e a respectiva chave? Ou seja, para este dicionário teria que retornar: 10, **D**.

Answer (score 1):

Faça:

```
meu_dict = {'A':3, 'B':5, 'C':0, 'D':10, 'E':2}
max_value = sorted(meu_dict.items(), key=lambda tup: tup[1])[-1] # ('D', 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> max(map(tuple, map(reversed, Meu_dic.items())))
(10, 'D')
```

EDIT:

Pensei numa outra maneira:

```
>>> max([i[::-1] for i in Meu_dic.items()])
(10, 'D')
```

Answer (score 0):

O mais simples possível:

```
key = max(dic, key=dic.get)
value = dic[key]
print key, value
```

`dic` é o seu dicionário.